# How to dismiss the parent div when we click div's anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs of same class name "parent". And with in, there are two child divs with class names, "child1" and "child2". The "child1" div has a p-tag and "child2" has an a-tag.

My question is, can the parent div be dismissed when I click on the child2's a-tag with out closing the other parent divs ??

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child1">
         <p>Paragraph</p>
     </div>
     <div class="child2">
         <a href="#">anchor</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Kindly check [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/LCB5W/28/) for understanding what I need.

Thanks a lot, Guys !

Comment: you don't mention it in your question but I'll ask anyway: with or without the use of jQuery?

Comment: Sorry! I need the code with the use of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dismiss the parent with a slid-up effect, like below.

```
$('.child2').click(function(e){
    //$(this).parents('.parent').remove();

     $(this).parents('.parent').slideUp('slow',function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/LCB5W/33/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
$('.child2').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nischaalc/LCB5W/29/

Comment: You can change the `fadeOut()` to a `hide()` if you want a more instantaneous dismissal.

Comment: The code you've given is working fine. But, in case, I have many tags in child2 and I want the parent to be dismissed when I click the particular tag, the code will not work. Right ?

Can you please update for this ?

Comment: If you want the parent to close only when you click a specific tag, you can change `.child2` in the jQuery code to the name of that tag.

Comment: Bro, I've checked the demo, you posted. I've updated that to this. Can't make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/LCB5W/35/

Comment: First let me make sure I understand you properly. You want to be able to remove the `parent` when you click on a specific `href` tag that is within `child2`. Correct? 
Will this specific `href` tag have a different name in each instance of `child2`?

Comment: priyan99 Found the solution. I need the solution like this.
http://jsfiddle.net/LCB5W/37/.

Thanks for your efforts, Bro.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
  $('.child2 a').click(function() {
    $(".parent").hide();
    $(this).closest(".parent").show();
    return false;
});
```

I update code just now!

Comment: in your case parent is child2... op is asking about to hide parent's parent

Comment: Buddy, Thanks. But, its closing everything.   :(

Answer (score 0):

Following is working for me

```
$('.child2 > a').each(function() {

    $(this).bind(
        "click",
        function() {

            $(this).closest( ".parent" ).fadeOut();
            //or  $(this).closest( ".parent" ).hide();
        });
  });
```

Check this also on jsfiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/LCB5W/31/

Comment: why the extra `each` loop? you can just use `$('.child2 > a').click();`.

Comment: Works too! Thank You, Pranay.